# GWT Suggestbox only show sugesstions when entered string is in alphabetic order

Tags: gwt, suggestbox

When I enter some text in `suggestbox` and if entered string is not matched alphabetically to the suggestions(i.e in `suggestionlist`); `suggestbox` do not show suggestions.

For example if suggestion list contain "will smith" and I enter "will" in suggestBox it will show me the suggestion but if I enter "smith" it will not show any suggestion.

BTW, I'm using `MultiWordSuggestOracle` for suggestions.

Comment: Can you share some code? I bet you can handle how the suggestions are matched on your own code, so you can achieve the desired behavior.

Comment: MultiWordSuggestOracle should find suggestions _containing_ query string, not necessarily _starting_ with query string. This is shown in the [documentation example](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/MultiWordSuggestOracle.html). Can you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?